# iexplore.exe.config is ignored

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, app-config

I need to override some settings for .NET components hosted inside Internet Explorer. I've created an iexplore.exe.config file and placed it in c:\program files\internet explorer.

Below is the config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <webRequestModules>
            <remove prefix="http:"/>
            <remove prefix="https:"/>
            <add prefix="http:" type="MyHttpRequestCreator, MyRequestModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bee8bd1bab54ad99" />
            <add prefix="https:" type="MyHttpRequestCreator, MyRequestModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bee8bd1bab54ad99" />
        </webRequestModules>
    </system.net>   
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, this seems to be completely ignored by IE. Even if I put invalid text in the file, no errors are logged.

This same configuration works perfectly if I added it to the machine.config, but I wanted to limit my overrides to IE if possible.

I tried enabling the IEHostLogFile (see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313892), and this gave me some interesting entries. It suggests that a remote configuration file is being loaded:

```
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Added configuration file: DotNetConfig.xml
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Application base: http://someserver/dotnet/
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Private Bin Path: bin
Microsoft.IE.IDKey: Created key
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Trying to create instance of type http://someserver/dotnet/
SomeApp.DLL#SomeApp.SomeClass
...
```

I examined that config file, and it doesn't override the system.net section, so I should still be able to provide my overrides. I could try modifying that file, but this solution wouldn't work for me as I don't want *everybody* who uses this application to be affected, just specific machines.

Ideas?

Comment: Just checking... x86 or x64 OS? (only because if it's x64, you're likely to actually want it placed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer`)

Comment: My testing has been on both an x86 and x64 machines, and I've placed the config in both locations on the x64 machine - just to be safe. The default IE is 32bit, and that's the one I'm launching, but I was stabbing the dark at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it helps when you put the following in your hostig websites head:

```
<link rel="Configuration" href="your.config"/>
```

Checkout the following link. pretty old thou, but maybe this hasnt changed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719757(vs.71).aspx

If this solves the issue, you could think about how to include this only for certain machines.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but unfortunately I don't "own" the target web site or sites.

Comment: +1, I don't believe IE uses iexplore.exe.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx

Comment: Sascha appears to be correct, despite some misleading documentation from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

[This article notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229689%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that:

> If an application hosted in Internet Explorer has a configuration
>   file, the location of this file is specified in a  tag with the
>   following syntax:
>
> `<link rel="ConfigurationFileName" href="location">`
>
> In this tag, location is a URL to the configuration file. This sets
>   the application base. The configuration file must be located on the
>   same Web site as the application.

Also please **look at reply by Dan Hickman in [this thread](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/6/31751.aspx)**. **Similar instructions are provided [here](http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Articles/ArticleTemplate.Aspx?ArticleID=1264)** (see in 'How to Embed Controls' section). All of them are about provided an appropriate access permissions.